how to make python 2.7 working in alma linux 9 with dnf
I have Alma Linux 9 in my VM, which is not compatible with python 2.7, but I need backward compatibility as well.
I had installed python2.7 from the source code and created a softlink between /usr/bin/python and /usr/local/bin/python2.7. It was working.
But, now I am unable to install any new packages using dnf.
I tried to make /usr/bin/python point back to python3.9. Now python is not working at all in my system. That is typing python in the terminal doesnot give any outputs.
I am trying to find a way in which dnf in alma linux 9 works with python 2

dnf is the name of your system packet manager? Just because you replace the simlink of  /usr/bin/python does not make packages from the repository dnf uses magically compatible with python 2 when they are packaged for python3. Make a local python 2.7 installation from source, which you have done, install pip and use that to install packages for your python 2.7.

Instead of meshing with the python versions installed on your system, you can create different environments using venv/conda/virtualenv to create isolated versions of Python without affecting one another.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
